# WCF equivalent to web reference (Kerberos & WebGate)

Tags: vb.net, wcf, authentication, oracle11g, kerberos

I hope you can help me with something.  I am trying to get my client-side WCF call to behave exactly the same as a web reference, which I have working correctly.

Web reference code:

```
Dim wsProxy As New Namespace.ServiceName()
wsProxy.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials
wsProxy.CookieContainer = New CookieContainer()
wsProxy.AllowAutoRedirect = True
wsProxy.WebMethod()
```

Nice and simple.  To my mind, the WCF equivalent should be:

```
Dim binding As New BasicHttpBinding(BasicHttpSecurityMode.TransportCredentialOnly)
binding.Security.Tranport.ClientCredentialType = HttpClientCredentialType.Windows
Dim wsProxy As New Namespace.ServiceName(binding, New EndpointAddress("..."))
wsProxy.ClientCredentials.Windows.AllowNtlm = False
wsProxy.ClientCredentials.Windows.AllowedImpersonationLevel = System.Security.Principal.TokenImpersonationLevel.Identification
wsProxy.ChannelFactory.Credentials.Windows.ClientCredential = Net.CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials
wsProxy.WebMethod()
```

No matter what I try, I can't get the WCF equivalent to authenticate.  I always get:

"The HTTP request is unauthorized with client authentication scheme 'Negotiate'.  The authentication header received from the server was 'Negotiate,Basic realm="My Realm"'."

Key criteria:

- Needs to authenticate using Kerberos
- The authentication procedure involves redirects before a 401 challenge.
- Cookies need to be persisted.

NOTE: Redirects and 401 are provided by Oracle Access Manager - but we know that there's nothing particularly exotic here, as the web reference works ok.

Any help much appreciated!

**Update 1**

Thanks for your question - in response to diggingforfile, the example above doesn't use a web.config.  However, if I do add a service reference, the following config is set up:

```
<basicHttpBinding>
  <binding name="SomeBindingName" closeTimeout="00:01:00"
      openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00"
      allowCookies="false" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
      maxBufferSize="65536" maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="65536"
      messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Buffered"
      useDefaultWebProxy="true">
      <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384"
          maxByesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384"
      <security mode="None">
          <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None"
              realm="" />
          <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />
      </security>
  </binding>
<basicHttpBinding>
<client>
  <endpoint address="http://Server/Service"
    binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="SomeBindingName"
    contract="Namespace.ServiceName" name="SomeEndpointName" />
</client>
```

If I try this, I get:

"The HTTP request is unauthorized with client authentication scheme 'Anonymous'.  The authentication header received from the server was 'Negotiate,Basic realm="My Realm"'."

Comment: N.B. To clarify what's going on behind the scenes, the WebReference solution responds to the 401 challenge with a request including the following header: "Authorization: Negotiate ENCODEDSTUFFENCODEDSTUFFENCODEDSTUFF". The WCF call simply doesn't respond to the challenge.

Comment: Can you post your web.config for the WCF service? As well, did you generate the client by pointing it to the service? If so, it should generate the correct web/app.config with the correct settings for security.

Comment: You've set the ClientCredentialType to none and the webserver does not allow anonymous. I'm not sure about the negotiate part, but you could try setting the ClientCredentialType to `Windows` - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.httptransportsecurity.clientcredentialtype.aspx